# What is the point of intersection of a line defined by 2 points with the plane $y=0$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

> Referred to the origin $O$, the points $P$ and $Q$ have position vectors **i** + $2$**j** + $3$**k** and $3$**i** + $3$**j** + $5$**k** respectively. Find the position vector of the point where the line $PQ$ meets the plane $y=0$
>   .

I’ve found the direction of line $PQ$:

$\overrightarrow{PQ}$

$= \overrightarrow {OQ} - \overrightarrow {OP}$

$=$ $3$**i** + $3$**j** + $5$**k** - ( **i** + $2$**j** + $3$**k**)

$=$ $2$**i** + **j** + $2$**k**

So, the vector equation of line $PQ$ is **r** =  **i** + $2$**j** + $3$**k** + $\lambda$($2$**i** + **j** + $2$**k**)

To find the position vector of the point of intersection between line $PQ$ and the plane $y=0$, I understand that I need to substitute **r** =  **i** + $2$**j** + $3$**k** + $\lambda$($2$**i** + **j** + $2$**k**) into the equation of plane, **r**$\cdot$**n** = $d$, where **n** is a vector perpendicular to the plane and $d$ is a constant.

Is it right to assume that **n**= $\left(\begin{matrix}2\\1\\2\\\end{matrix}\right)$ ?

How  do I find the value of $d$? How do I apply the information of plane $y=0$?

Any hints would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: I have taken the liberty to give a more accurate title to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line can be parameterised by $p(t) = (1,2,3)+t ( (3,3,5) - (1,2,3)) = (1,2,3)+t(2,1,2)$.

You want to find the $t^*$ such that $[p(t^*)]_2 = 0$.

This gives $0 = 2+t^*$ or $t^* = -2$.

Hence the point is $p(t^*) = (-3,0,-1)$.

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct, but I don’t quite understand your notation of $[p(t^*)]_2$ . May I ask what does $t^*$ stand for?

Comment: Each $t$ corresponds to a different point on the line, $p(0)$ is $P$, $p(1)$ is $Q$, etc. So, $t^*$ is the particular value of $t$ such that the second component of the point is zero.

Answer (score 0):

All points in line $PQ$ are in the form of $a\vec{P}+b\vec{Q}, a+b=1$.

Now look at the $\hat{j}$ component, since it needs to be zero then $2a+3b=0$. Solving the two equations yields $a=3$ and $b=-2$